# Crop Images in an Image Grid Evenly

Tags: css, reactjs

I am developing a React application to display a grid of images by fetching the URLs from a Firestore database. This is what my `ImageGrid` component looks like,

```
import React from "react";
import useFirestore from "../hooks/useFirestore";

const ImageGrid = () => {
    const {docs} = useFirestore("images");

    return (
        <div className="img-grid">
            {docs && docs.map((doc) => (
                <div className="img-wrap" key={doc.id}>
                    <img src={doc.url} alt="uploaded pic"/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ImageGrid;
```

The CSS I have used for this component looks like this,

```
.img-grid{
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 40px;
}
.img-wrap{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  padding: 50% 0;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrap img{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

The issue I am facing is that when my images are of different sizes, they do not get cropped evenly. They get copped from only one side: the right.

How can I fix this, so that my images are cropped evenly?

Comment: This would be easier to replicate and solve if you had a code snippet, but maybe try adding `object-fit: cover` to the `.img-wrap img` CSS rule.

Comment: Hey! I already tried that and it did not work, unfortunately. By code snippet, what else do you want apart from what I have provided already?

Comment: Actually I was just able to replicate it, and setting the `max-width` property to "100%" seems to work.

Comment: I already tried this as well. It does technically work, but what it does it that it compresses the image and then it does not look as great. I don't mind the image gets cropped, but I want it to be even.

Comment: Okay, I may have figured something out. Replace `min-width` and `min-height` with `width` and `height`, keeping values at 100%, then add `object-fit: contain`.

Comment: Do I need to make any changes to the other attributes. This resizes the images so that they are not cropped, but makes each of them appear in different sizes, which is not ideal.

Comment: Since none of my suggestions seem to be working, and I don't know how exactly your images are rendering, I think it would be best for you to reproduce the HTML in a code snippet with the exact images you are using for me to most easily help you.